# Class cast exception occurred on using array in for each loop (via Jar)?

Tags: java, generics

As I am new to Java, I have few doubts regarding Java generics behavior. Here I have implemented own List functionality using native list as wrapper. Below is the code,

```
ListWrapper<String> li = new ListWrapper<String>(); // wrapper for native list implemented
li.add(“Hello”);
```

Iterated the elements in the list by converting the list items to array and used in foreach loop.

```
//Method which used to convert as array in ListWrapper.
public T[] toArray() {
return (T[]) _list.toArray(); // _list is the native list (i.e) java.util.List which converts list items to object[] array.
}
```

On using this method in for-each loop faced **class-cast exception only on compiled class(.jar)** but works properly on attaching the source.

```
for(Object s : li.toArray()) { // Class cast exception occurred here.
System.out.println(s);
}
```

**My understanding:**

toArray() in the for-each loop will be called once and iterator will be called implicitly to iterate over the elements.  **As I have casted the toArray() as T[] (here T will be of String)**, hence Iterator will try to access the object[] array. So, class cast exception of [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String occurred. Please correct me if am wrong.

Also, I would like to know why the same code works properly while running by attaching the source. Can anyone clarify for me?

Comment: Can you show your `ListWrapper`?

Comment: Just to be sure: you know that you can iterate lists easily by simple implementing the **Iterable** interface on your class? There is absolutely no need to convert your list to an array just for iterating. In any case, please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. As written right now, answering isnt possible, and boils down to wild guessing.

Comment: *"why the same code works properly while running by attaching the source"* — I cannot reproduce this. It's also hard to believe, however, it's not entirely impossible. It may be due to cache or whatever.

Comment: Regarding the `ClassCastException`: `T` in the cast `(T[])` is indeed of type `String`, so you cast the result of `_list.toArray()` to a `String[]`. But that's the very reason a `ClassCastException` is emitted: `_list.toArray()` does not return a `String[]`, but rather an `Object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, an array object knows its component type at runtime, and so when creating an array, you need to provide the component type at runtime. On the other hand, an instance of a generic class does not know its component type at runtime. For a `List<T>` instance, it doesn't by default know what `T` is at runtime, so there is no way it can create an array with a runtime component type of `T`.

`List`'s `toArray()` method with no arguments will always create an array with a runtime component type of `Object`. This array will always have the runtime class `Object[]`; it cannot be `String[]` or `Integer[]` or whatever. A variable of type `String[]` cannot point to this object, since `Object[]` is not a subtype of `String[]`, so it will cause a `ClassCastException`. (And by the way, all this was true before there was generics; generics improved some of the signatures, but the runtime behavior is the same.) Your cast to `T[]` is fundamentally unsafe.

When you do unsafe casts in generics, it can cause `ClassCastException`s in other places where there isn't an explicit cast. It will not cause a `ClassCastException` where you cast to `T[]`, because `T` is erased to `Object` (`T`'s upper bound), so the erased code is just casting `Object[]` to `Object[]`. However, the fact that the method returns `T[]` means that the caller of the method, if they have a specific type for `T`, can cast the return result. So here, the caller expects `li.toArray()` to return type `String[]` (since `li` has type `ListWrapper<String>`, so `T` is `String`, and `ListWrapper.toArray()` returns `T[]`). So it can insert a cast of the result to `String[]`, even though you don't see a cast in the code. That is why you get a `ClassCastException` there.

(Now, you could argue that technically it doesn't need to cast to `String[]`, since it's used in a foreach loop, and each element is assigned to a variable of type `Object`, so it is valid to leave `li.toArray()` as `Object[]` and not cast. But it is also permissible for the compiler to cast it anyway; and here, the compiler decided to insert a cast.)

`List` has another `toArray()` method, which takes one argument of array type. This method will either use the passed array object to store the results, or extract the runtime component type out of the passed array object, and create a new array object with the same runtime component type. So the returned array object will have the same runtime class as the passed array object. So you can use this `toArray()` method to get an array object whose runtime class is a more specific array type than `Object[]`, but you will have to give an array object of the right type at runtime.

If you want to implement a type-safe `.toArray()` method in your `ListWrapper` class, you would have to do something like what `List` does -- either it must always return an array with runtime class `Object[]`, and therefore it must be returned in type `Object[]`; and/or it must take in an array object as an argument to extract the runtime component type from, to create an array object of the right component type.